# Select all categories for each K2 item

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

I am having a issue with querying the Joomla K2 article manager database tables. I want to be able to select all items joined with their respective categories. I have most of the query done as follows:

```
$query->clear()
   ->select('i.id, i.title as name, c.name as cat, i.published')
   ->from('#__k2_items AS i')
   ->join('LEFT', '#__k2_categories AS c ON c.id = i.catid')
   ->where('i.published > 0')
   ->order('i.title, i.ordering, i.id');
```

This gives me what I want except for it only selects the FIRST category the item is related to. I believe it is because in the `k2_items` table the `catid` column is a of type `varchar` and has the categories comma separated.

e.g

So say k2_item with id 1 has a `catid` value of `123,124,125` the query above will only display the result for `123`. I need it to display the rows for `123`, `124` and `125`.

Any help would be great. 
Thanks

Comment: If it was me, I'd create a VIEW of same (minus the WHERE and ORDER), and then do the rest in Joomla

Comment: Sorry could you expand on your answer a little. I havent used a view in SQL before (but I can look that up). What do you mean do the rest in joomla.

Comment: Hm, I slightly mis-read your question (although the principle of using views in this way is still relevant). Also take a look at FIND_IN_SET(). I don't really know Joomla but, if you're still struggling, post up proper DDLs (and or an sqlfiddle) and someone here will provide a MySQL solution which you can then 'reverse-engineer' into your Joomla syntax.

Comment: I have created a sqlfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfc24/3 thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT i.id
     , i.title name
     , c.name cat 
  FROM k2_items i
  LEFT
  JOIN k2_categories c 
    ON FIND_IN_SET(c.id,i.catid)>0;

ID  NAME    CAT
1   item 1  Category 1
1   item 1  Category 2
2   item 2  Category 1
2   item 2  Category 2
2   item 2  Category 3
3   item 3  Category 2
3   item 3  Category 3
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfc24/5

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you. If I had enough rep to up the answer I would as well.

Comment: This is NOT beautiful! Beautiful would be a properly normalized schema! Unfortunately, this might be a limitation of Joomla.

Comment: Beautiful in the sense it did what I wanted it to do. Unfortunately I cant change the schema of the tables that I am querying. The query time of FIND_IN_SET is 93ms. Without is 3ms. Is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: That is a limitation of a non-normalized design.